# Testing disputes on the local currency payments

Tags: facebook, transactions, payment, facebook-credits, real-time-updates

Facebook has launched the new local currency payments API recently. Does anyone know what the format of the data that facebook sends to the real time update url is? Has anyone found documentation about?
Also is there a way to test disputes without having to actually dispute a real purchase?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the Realtime Updates, I think this might be the info you're looking for: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/fulfillment/#rtu

And regarding disputes, from my experience working with Facebook's payment systems, I'd venture to guess that such an option does not exist<strike>, and probably never will, because they hate us and want to be hard to work with</strike>.

Comment: Definitely true! I agree.